# Django Copy Related Data and keep them unchanged over time

Tags: django, django-models

Using ForeignKey relationships, I want to be able to copy data and store it in another model.  For example, think of how you would handle past Invoices and billed Services.

The Invoice would have one or more Services associated with it and with prices for the Services. This prices for a Service can / will change over time - but the Service price recorded with the Invoice should remain as it was when the Invoice was created.

My first thought was to create a pdf from the resulting data and store it. But this would make the data somewhat inaccessible.

Is there somehow a way to copy the data and keep them accessible?

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty broad problem with multiple solutions. I dont think that what you're aiming to is the correct one.

One rule for saving invoices is, that invoices never change. You should never update an invoice. So not only your 'copies' of invoices should remain the same, but the original too.

Also, you should have a InvoiceItem (or InvoiceRow) model which are the items on your invoice. Don't bind Products to a Invoice directly.

Here are 2 solutions I've used:

**Solution 1**

You can normalize the data on your invoice(items). So, don't use foreignkeys, but normalize all data about the product, so product info (incl. price) is saved within the invoice(item).

**Solution 2**

Give your products revision numbers. So everytime a product is updated (name or price change for example), a new product is created in the database. Now you can link the InvoiceItem to a Product with a Foreign Key, and it will will be historically accurate.

Im sure there are some guides/best practices for creating Invoice backends. Language or Framework is not important. Invoicing is really important, so do alot of research before starting to build something. That's just my two pennies

Comment: Yes its pretty broad - but I think it is a common problem. Whould it be better placed at /programmers/?

Comment: I think thats a better place for this question indeed. But, as you mention, this is indeed a common problem. I doubt noone has ever asked this before, or made a good blogpost about it ;)